# How do I make an embed in discord?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, nextcord, pycord

How to make embed in discord, whenever I send an embed using `ctx.send(embed)` it just sends `<embed object at 0x0000>` and not the embed

Comment: What does the documentation say? What did you learn when you googled `how to make discord.py embed`?

Answer (score 1):

The basic code for making an embed is:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description")
embed.add_field(name="Field 1", value="Value of field 1", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Field 2", value="Value of field 2", inline=True)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

- if your embed name is `embedName`, you can use something like this

```py
await ctx.send(embed=embedName)
```

- You can create + visualise + generate a code snippet for the embed with [this tool](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/) easily
- Learn more about discord Embeds from [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this code:

```
embed = nextcord.Embed(title="title", description="descripion", color=0x000ff)
embed.add_field(name="field", value="value", inline=False)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you don't want to write the code by yourself, you can use [this link](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these: (not my code)

```
async def make_embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Waiting for a title')
    title = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Waiting for a description')
    desc = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=0x72d345)
    await ctx.send(embed=embd)



async def make_embed(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description = content.split('|')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x72d345)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```